# Java Stack push() vs add()

Tags: java, collections, interface, stack

I am trying to use `Stack`, but I am slightly confused by the terminology.

I find that `Stack` class has only `push(E e)` as per Java doc.

And has `add(E e)` and `addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)` as a inherited method from `Vector` class.

Do they have the same functionality or is it better to use `push(...)` to insert elements to the `Stack` object.

In other words, will I encounter any issues if I use `add(...)` instead of `push(...)`?

Comment: those are legacy classes not very used anymore. what are you trying to do?

Comment: An unfortunate side effect of extending from `Vector`, which should not have been done.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Kalyanaraman Santhanam:
>
> Edit: Will I encounter any issues if I use add(...) instead of
> push(...)?

Definitly, you will not encounter any issues, because `add` is part of `List` interface as well as the `Stack`, but you should to notice the further readability of your code and your intentions in it by other programmers. `push` method will give them a clue that they're using the `Stack` object, they will know certantly what to expect from. Also notice that `push` has different return value than `add` (the former has "pushed object" type and the latter just a `boolean` response)

Comment: Example :  `Deque` interface has `void addFirst(E e);`  and `void push(E e);` which are similar in behaviour including the return type.     from the java doc it says   **<p>This method is equivalent to {@link #addFirst}.**

Answer (score 8):

The only difference is the return type

```
System.out.println(stack.push("1"));

Output : 1

System.out.println(stack.add("2"));

Output : true
```

But it is recommended to use Push method for Stack

Answer (score 4):

(sorry if my english is bad, i'm from MX).

Theorically, is the same thing, because add is a method of all the generic class... But is very recommendable to use push, because you are using a stack and if you use "push" method instead of "add", maybe you'll understand a little bit more...

Answer (score 3):

They are the same.

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#push%28E%29):

> Pushes an item onto the top of this stack. This has exactly the same
>   effect as:
>
> ```
> addElement(item)
> ```

Comment: But isnt addElement() and add() two different functions ?

Answer (score 3):

As everyone said, it has same effect with "push". Some may ask, but why? I recently read this subject, and it was saying it is a violation of principle "principle of least astonishment". So it is like a design flaw of API, not a major issue. This teaches us, no software, framework, API, etc.. are perfect, everything has its own flaws.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `Stack` then you should use `push()` as this is the standard way to add elements onto a stack (due to the idea of the data structure of a `Stack`). This means that the "top of the stack" is the item you've just `push()`ed.

You should only ever add and remove from the top of a `Stack` and if you think you will need other ways of adding data (add to middle or end) then I would advise against using a `Stack` as it will make your code harder to understand.

Edit: (reflecting question edit)
As I've mentioned, I would **not** expect to see `add()` if I was dealing with a `Stack`. `add()` is not the standard syntax for using a `Stack`, `push()` is. I would recommend only using the functions defined in the main body of the `javadoc` unless you specifically need those that are inherited.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah ,I can't find much difference between push() and add() method on using them.But preferred to use push() while using Stack

Answer (score 1):

What i recently encountered while attempting a coding question (actually the situation which led me to search the same question) is :
My code was exceeding time limit when i used stack.add(string object).
While it resolved successfully as i changed .add to .push
i.e. stack.push(string object).
Literally i had changed nothing else (except .add -> .push), and my code executed in time!

Answer (score 0):

It is all about inheritance issues, if it is a `Stack` you should use `push()` to be clear and follow to the model. But, in fact from Java SE spec:

*Pushes an item onto the top of this stack. This has exactly the same effect as:* `addElement(item)`

Answer (score 0):

> From my analysis, I could see no difference between the output of the add and push methods. Please refer the code and the output below..

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackDemo {

    static Stack stack = new Stack();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        add(10);
        add(20);
        add(30);
        print();
        push(40);
        print();
        pop();
        print();
        push(50);
        print();

    }

    static void print() {
        System.out.println(stack);
    }

    static void add(int item) {
        stack.add(item);
    }

    static void push (int item) {
        stack.push(item);
    }

    static void peek() {
        System.out.println(stack.peek());
    }

    static int pop() {
        return stack.pop();
    }
}
```

```
*
[10, 20, 30]
[10, 20, 30, 40]
[10, 20, 30]
[10, 20, 30, 50]
*
```